# Pattern for A@B

Tags: java, regex

What pattern should I use for A@B with A can contain 1-16 digits and B contains 1-18 digits?

I have used the pattern :

```
String regex = "\\d+@\\d+";
```

But the above pattern accepts more than 16-digits for `'A'` and more than 18-digits for `'B'`.
What pattern should I use for this.

**Note :**  The total length must be 32 characters or less.

Comment: one more thing both A and B are numeric no other characters allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the long version of the [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `{n,m}`, where n is the minimum amount and m is the maximum amount of repetitions.

What makes it difficult is your total length of 32 chars. To ensure that you need a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
^(?=.{1,32}$)\d{1,16}@\d{1,18}$
```

`^` and `$` are anchors for the start and the end of the string to avoid parital matches (depends on the method in Java if you need them)

`(?=.{1,32}$)` is a lookahead assertion that ensures the string has between 1 and 32 chars in total.

or as Java string

```
String regex = "^(?=.{1,32}$)\\d{1,16}@\\d{1,18}$";
```

Comment: Upvoting for perfect yet brief answer. Been enjoying cruising through some of your regex posts. :)

Comment: @zx81, glad to hear that you enjoy my posts!

Comment: @stema You sure have been busy in the regex tag. It's a fun cruise.

Answer (score 0):

```
\\d{1,16}@\\d{1,18}
```

should do it for you.

According to your regex , it will match from 1 to infinite times i.e. `+`.

also I will like to tell about `*` , it matches from zero to infinite times.

**update**

Getting 32 digits is more important than anything else.
So we ll better use :

```
[\d@]{32}
```

Comment: Its OK, But it is accepting more than 32 characters, i.e. the length must be 32 charterers or less. Can we do it with the patten matching.

Comment: @vermaraj it depends whether you want the first 32 or last 32 characters . suppse you enter : `4234234242342342@345345345345344444` it matches your condition of 16 chars before @ and 18 chars after @ but putting the third condtion of 32 chars which 32 chars you would like to keep ?

Comment: @vermaraj thats exactly where the confusion is, you said just now : `12345@12345678912345678912345678 or 12345678912345678912345678@12345 are valid patterns ` but how ? now your B can accept more than 18 digits ?  or your A can accept more than 16 digits ?? check your length in first example B is 26 digits and in second A is 26 digits ?? You will have to stick to one condition.

Comment: I think @stema has given the perfect answer for this. please vote me up instead of voting down, because he/she has understand the problem at first ..

Comment: @vermaraj but your question and explanations were wrong. you have deleted your comments where you had provided a sample string

Answer (score 0):

Try using the repetition character that lets you specify ranges:

```
\\d{1,16}@\\d{1,18}
```

Comment: Ah, aelor totally beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
\\d{1,16}@\\d{1,15}|\\d{1,13}@\\d{1,18}
```

The total length will not be more than 32.
(You can check in the regex tester http://myregexp.com/?regex=%5Cd%7B1,16%7D@%5Cd%7B1,15%7D%7C%5Cd%7B1,13%7D@%5Cd%7B1,18%7D&text=12345@1234567)